# Move down when tab key pressed

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I'm trying to move the focus to the next field/button but it doesn't seem to want to work. Here is what I currently have:

```
    @Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB) 
    {   
        //move down here once I figure it out..
        mEmailvalue.getNextFocusDownId();
        return true;

       }  
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB && event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View currentFocus = getCurrentFocus();
        if (currentFocus!=null) {
            View next = currentFocus.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            if (next!=null) {
                next.requestFocus();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }  
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```